# How to increase thickness of lines in Line Charts?

Tags: asp.net, charts

How can we increase the thickness of the lines in `Line` charts (`System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting`)? I tried to change the `Font` property of the `Series`, but found that it's read-only.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
chart1.Series["Default"].BorderWidth = 2;
```

Very helpful collection of examples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61

Comment: It's ridiculously unintuitive that the width of a line in a line graph is controlled by "BorderWidth". Thanks, Microsoft, for this WTF.

Comment: The link is dead, do you know of any alternatives?

Answer (score 5):

Click On chart, then you will see a Values filled and category groups Box on right side of graph, then in Values filled, right-click on any values Go to "Series Properties" --> "Border " -- > "Line Width" and then set the size.

Comment: I am newbie and from your comment I came to know about accessing series group properties.